# Passing data from table to first View controller - Error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I try to pass the selected table row back to my first view controller, it gives an error that an option is nil.

However, I can print the value of the variables I want to pass.

View Controllers are in this order.

1. Adding a new "item" to inventory
2. Select new VC to choose a "category" and then another VC to select a Subcategory.
3. From those you can goto another VC to create category and subcategories.

Project Source @
https://github.com/GadgetAddict/InventoryApp

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,  didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let dict = items[indexPath.row]

    let selectedSub = dict["subname"] as! String

    let newCat = Category(catName: passedCategory, subcatName: selectedSub)
    print(newCat.catName)
    print(newCat.subcatName)

    delegate.setCats(newCat)

    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this and perhaps post some code snippets on which lines are giving you problems?

Comment: Updated above,  When I run this,  it gets to the delegate.setCats(newcat) and breaks.  I have the prints above to make sure both of those vars had values...    I tried passing them as strings before with the same outcome. Fatal Error:  found nil when unwrapping an optional

Comment: I went through the codes in your Github project and realized that `setCat` function takes a string, but it seems like you are passing a `Category` object  in your codes posted above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted the only possible way you get such error is here where you make an explicit cast:

```
let selectedSub = dict["subname"] as! String
```

However you should debug a little and see which line crashes exactly because it could be in your other controller as well.

Answer (score 1):

I went through your codes on Github and realized that you did not set the delegate before displaying DestinationViewController. Hence, I believe if you put a breakpoint on that line `delegate.setCat("something")`, you will see that your delegate is value is set to `nil`.

There are two ways around this. First is to continue with delegation pattern, where your code should look something like this; before presenting the DestinationViewController so that the `delegate` value not `nil`.

```
let subCatVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourSubCatStoryboardIdentifier") as! SubcategoryVC
subcatvc.delegate = self
```

The next thing I will say may not be entirely corect, it is just how I assume the underlying architecture of iOS works.

Delegation methods are tricky to be carried across multiple screens. For example, your app goes to NewItemVC -> CategoryVC -> SubCategoryVC, so the `delegate` you initialized at NewItemVC, by the time you reach SubCategoryVC would probably be `nil` because either its memory has not been allocated yet when you set it at NewItemVC or it is reset by the time you reach CategoryVC.

So I will suggest using NSNotificationCenter to pass your data from DestionationVC back to NewItemVC. The codes should look along the lines of something like this:

*NewItemVC.swift*

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
 super.viewDidLoad()
 let notifCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
 notifCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(NewItemVC.setCat), name: "setCategoryNotification", object: nil)
}

func setCat(notification:NSNotification){

    let userInfo:Dictionary<String,String!> = notification.userInfo as Dictionary<String,String!>
    //your selected category can be extracted here
    let selectedCategory = userInfo["selectedCategory"]
}
```

*SubCategoryVC.swift*

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,  didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let dict = items[indexPath.row]

    let selectedSub = dict["subname"] as! String

    let newCat = Category(catName: passedCategory, subcatName: selectedSub)
    print(newCat.catName)
    print(newCat.subcatName)

    let notifCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
     notifCenter.postNotificationName("setCategoryNotification",
                            object:nil,
                            userInfo:["selectedCategory":selectedSub])

    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I realize that it was a lot of code to review and delegates and swift are all so new to me that it was difficult to wrap my head around this.

Comment: No worries. I understand that iOS development does not have the easier learning curve. Hope I helped you understand a little bit more.